# Grails GORM searching for list items that match another list

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have three objects:

Teacher,
Child,
Parent

Teacher.students is a List of Child objects

Parent.children is also a List of Child objects

I want to find all the Teachers who teach a certain Parent's children.

I tried this but it only finds teachers of one child.  I need this to work if a parent has multiple children.

```
def teachers = Teacher.withCriteria{ 
    students { 
        inList("id", parent.children.first().id ) 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only grabbing the first id; you need to use *all* the childrens' id's, which you can get using the spread (`*`) operator.  Also, according to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html#main), the method is `in`, not `inList` for criteria, but it's possible I may be missing something about the version, etc.:

```
in("id", parent.children*.id)
```